# Padding with p and td html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

i have a problem with my p tag and td. For some reason it seems the p does not take the whole space inside the td.

[here is the link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEcJL)

i tried alot of things like changing the display and nothing fixed it.

Comment: Paragraphs don't expand to consume all available space unless you explicitly say so using the `height` property.

Comment: i replace my p with divs and the result is exactly the same. Can i set the height to be the highest value in the table without it being hard coded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Cimmanon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon), paragraphs require an explicit height property in order to occupy all of a `th` or `td` space, such as `height: 3em` or `height: 50px`

edit: `div`'s work the same as paragraphs inside `th` and `td`